# unit testing - jest with supertest gives a timeout

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, express, jestjs, supertest

I got an error running my unit tests. I am using a express app from NodeJS. I want to test the return message (200) and (eventually) the output of a function.

```
const {Router} = require('express');
const {query} = require('../dbConfig');

module.exports = (router = new Router()) => {
    //get only one user from the id
    router.post('/getUser', async (req,res)=>{
        id = req.body.id;
        sql = "SELECT lastname, firstname, email, title_id, id, state FROM users WHERE id=" + id;
        let result = await query(sql);
        if(result.length >= 1){
            res.send(result[0]);
        }

    })
    return router;
};
```

But when I try to run the following test :

```
const app = require('../../app')
const request = require('supertest')
jest.mock('../../dbConfig');;

describe('POST /getUser', () => {
    let data = {
        id:1
    }

    it('Response 200 + response type',(done)=>{
        request.agent(app)
            .post('/getUser')
            .send(data)
            .expect(200, done)
    })
});
```

It returns me the following error

```
Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 5000ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.
```

I tried diffrent variations without success... I also tried the doc online which wasn't really helpful for this error... I run jest with `npx jest` and the mock file looks like this :

```
const rep={
    "lastname": "admin",
    "firstname": "admin",
    "email": "admin@etsmtl.ca",
    "title_id": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "state": 1
};


const query = (sqli) =>{
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{
        console.log("SQL request : " + sqli)
        if(sqli === "SELECT lastname, firstname, email, title_id, id, state FROM users WHERE id=1"){
            console.log("Passed")
            resolve(rep);
        }
    });

}

module.exports = {query};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `query` method returns an object (`rep`), and you check the length of it in the `POST` handler. The length of an object is `undefined`, so it doesn't reach the `res.send`. You need to set an `else` option with another `res.send` so it answers the client no matter what happens. Also, you probably want to change that `if` in the `POST` handler, or the format of the return in the mock file.

For instance, in your Mock file:

```
const query = (sqli) =>{
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{
        console.log("SQL request : " + sqli)
        if(sqli === "SELECT lastname, firstname, email, title_id, id, state FROM users WHERE id=1"){
            console.log("Passed")
            resolve([rep]); //Now it's an array of length 1, reaches the first send
        } else {
            reject([]); //Length is 0, so it will reach the second send
        }
    });

}
```

Controller

```
if(result.length >= 1){
    res.send(result[0]);
} else {
    res.status(500).send('Something broke!');
}
```

Comment: Thanks you! I always forget to take errors in consideration but, trust me, now I will!

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure your db is initialized? Can you try this at your controller?

```
router.post('/getUser', async (req,res)=>{
    id = req.body.id;
    sql = "SELECT lastname, firstname, email, title_id, id, state FROM users WHERE id=" + id;
    try {
       let result = await query(sql);
       if(result.length >= 1){
           res.send(result[0]);
       } else {
           res.sendStatus(404);
       }
    } catch(err) {
       res.sendStatus(500)
    }

})
```

In case your db isnt correctly initialized, or if query throws an error, it will never respond

Comment: Actually, as you can see in the test, the "query" method is mocked.. So it besically returns fake data just for testing purposes. And the function also works when I try it from postman so only the unit test have someting wrong...

Comment: @etiennnr Well, the reason you had a timeout still was the lack of an else/catch